# SetProperty does not fire change event

Tags: javafx, observablecollection, changelistener, valuechangelistener

I have a SetProperty

```
private final SetProperty<String> origins = new SimpleSetProperty<>(FXCollections.observableSet(new TreeSet<>()));
```

If I modify this Property this way everything works as expected (My TableView is notified about the change)

```
this.origins.setValue(FXCollections.observableSet(new LinkedHashSet<>(origins)));
```

If I modify this Property this way, my TableView is not notified

```
this.origins.clear();
this.origins.addAll(origins);
```

Since the value for this property is an observable set, I would expect the SetProperty to be notified about changes of the underlying set and also propagate this change event to it's listeners (in this case the TableView).

The TableView is created as follows:
FXML:

```
[..]
<TableView fx:id="table" GridPane.columnIndex="0"
GridPane.rowIndex="1" editable="true"
GridPane.hgrow="always" GridPane.vgrow="always">
<columns>
    <TableColumn text="Files">
        <cellValueFactory>
            <PropertyValueFactory property="origins" />
        </cellValueFactory>
    </TableColumn>
</columns>
</TableView>
[..]
```

The data bean looks like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractPeakBean extends VeryAbstractPeakBean implements PeakBean {


private final SetProperty<String> origins = new SimpleSetProperty<>(FXCollections.observableSet(new TreeSet<>()));


public void addAllOrigins(Collection<String> origins) {

    this.origins.addAll(origins);
}

@Override
public AbstractPeakBean addOrigin(String origin) {

    this.origins.add(origin);
    return this;
}

@Override
public Collection<String> getOrigins() {

    return Collections.unmodifiableCollection(origins);
}

@Override
public SetProperty<String> originsProperty() {

    return origins;
}

@Override
public AbstractPeakBean setAllOrigins(Collection<String> origins) {

    this.origins.clear();
    this.origins.addAll(origins);
    this.origins.setValue(FXCollections.observableSet(new LinkedHashSet<>(origins)));
    return this;
}

public void setOrigins(Collection<String> origins) {

    this.origins.clear();
    this.origins.addAll(origins);
}
}
```

Comment: You didn't provide code that allows us to reproduce the issue. Also it's unclear, how the `TableView` works with the set... Also a set containing the same elements could easily be equal to the original set...

Answer (score 1):

I have made a little example to test you problem and it works as expected:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SetProperty<String> origins = new SimpleSetProperty<>(FXCollections.observableSet(new TreeSet<>()));
    origins.addListener( (obs, ov, nv) -> System.out.println("ChangeListener was called"));
    origins.addListener( (SetChangeListener.Change<?> change) -> System.out.println("SetListener was called"));

    origins.set(FXCollections.observableSet(new TreeSet<>()));
    origins.get().add("Test1");
    origins.get().add("Test1");
    origins.get().clear();
    origins.get().clear();
}
```

As you can see, there are two kinds of listeners the standard ChangeListener and a special SetChangeListener, which could be registered on a set property.
The standard ChangeListener fires every time the list was modified (add or remove actions) or replaced by a new ObservableList. The SetChangeListener only fires, if the list was modified.

The result:

```
ChangeListener was called
ChangeListener was called
SetListener was called
ChangeListener was called
SetListener was called
```

The first action from the example is a replacement of the whole list. This results in a call for all ChangeListeners but not the SetChangeListeners.

The second action adds "Test1" to the set and both listeners are executed.

The third action does not modify the set because "Test1" is already a member of the set and sets do not contain duplicates. No change -> no change event.

The 4th action removes "Test1" from the set and both listeners are executed.

The 5th action does (again) not modify the set because it was already empty.

---

**Update 1**

I made a little example application and I could change the current list and swap the whole list of a table view without problems:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    private VBox root;
    private TableView<String> tableView;
    private TableColumn<String, Character> lettersColumn;
    private ObservableList<String> items;
    private Scene scene;
    private Button button1;
    private Button button2;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        items.addAll("Aa", "Bb", "Cc");
        tableView = new TableView<>(items);
        lettersColumn = new TableColumn<>("FirstLetters");
        lettersColumn.setCellValueFactory( cellDataFeature ->
            new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(cellDataFeature.getValue().charAt(0))
        );

        tableView.getColumns().add(lettersColumn);

        button1 = new Button("Add item");
        button1.setOnMouseClicked( event -> items.add("Dd"));

        button2 = new Button("Swap whole list");
        button2.setOnMouseClicked( event -> {
            items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            items.addAll("1a", "2b", "3c");
            tableView.setItems(items);
        });

        root = new VBox(tableView, button1, button2);
        scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I hope this helps to find your problem.

---

**Update 2**
I found a bug within SimpleMapProperty and SimpleSetProperty. If you have more than 1 ChangeListener and at the same time no MapChangeListener/SetChangeListener registered on your property the Listeners wont be executed. This is a bug within MapExpressionHelper and SetExpressionHelper.

If you want to workaround it just register a empty Map/SetChangeListener and it will work again. E.g.:

```
setProperty.addListener((SetChangeListener.Change<?> change) -> {});
```

Comment: Many thanks for your explanations! Do you know what kind of listeners are registered on the SetProperty when it is used by a TableView configured via FXML (as shown above)?

Comment: Hmm I only found a WeakListChangeListener within the TabelView class. But because the TableView allows to swap the whole List (setItems) it must also watch for for those events too.

Comment: Hi Zerlono, many thanks for investigating on this. Unfortunately, it still does not work. Its true that I have multiple listeners registered on the SetPropery, maybe this is the problem. I tried your workaround using an "empty" change listener but it seems it does not make a difference.